# How to count duplicate prolog

Tags: prolog

I have implemented this tree (insertion), but i want to keep track of duplicate, how do i do this.

```
insert2(nil, nil, nil).
insert2(Info, nil, t((Info,1), nil, nil)).

insert2(Info , t((RootInfo,_), Left, Right),
          t((RootInfo,_), LeftPlus, Right)) :-
                      Info< RootInfo,
                      insert2(Info, Left, LeftPlus).


insert2(Info , t((RootInfo,count), Left, Right),t((RootInfo,count+1), Left, Right)) :-
                          Info= RootInfo.

insert2(Info, t((RootInfo,_), Left, Right),
                   t((RootInfo,_), Left, RightPlus)) :-
     RootInfo< Info,
     insert2(Info, Right, RightPlus).
```

To be a bit more clear this is what i mean

```
-? T = t((20,3),t((10,1),nil,nil),t((30,2),nil,nil)),
insertT(10,T,NT).
NT = t((20,3), t((10,2),nil,nil),t((30,2),nil,nil)).
```

Since i have already inserted 10, the tree will just increase the counter instead of adding a duplicate value. Thanks

Comment: Start with a list of items, and only then try a tree. There is too much to understand at the same time.

Comment: I do know how to count duplicate with  a list, that's why i moved on with trees

Comment: You do not say this in your question.

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't get your point, i'm doing something i'm stuck, so i asked for help, if it's too much i can remove my question!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand how this site works.

Comment: One thing that needs fixing: `RootInfo < Info` isn't right. In place of `RootInfo` in your predicate clause head, you should have, `(RootInfo, Count)` and then compare the `RootInfo < Info` will make sense. In some clause you need to be updating count. That should occur if `RootInfo = Info`.

Comment: Identify where a node is first added to the tree. That's where the count is set to `1`. Your second clause already has that case, although I haven't examined your code close enough to know if it's correct (I'm hoping you'll figure it out first :)). Another error: `insert2(Info , t((RootInfo,count), ...`: the lower case `count` is not a variable.

Comment: That's what i did except the typo with the Lower case :((

Comment: im so sorry it's all typos had a long week. i think you made me realize i have to go to beg early :(

Comment: Actually you are very, very close and the logic is basically correct. You just need the variable `Count` and you can't add `1` to it *in line* like you are attempting in your 4th clause. You need something like a `Count1 is Count + 1` in the clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're so very close, I'll tidy it up. :)

The only real issues remaining with what you have are:

1. You have an atom instead of variable for `Count` in one of the clauses
2. You're attempting to add *in line* with Prolog, which doesn't really work that way. If you try to use `Count + 1` as an argument, it will be read as the term, `+(Count, 1)` unless it gets passed into a predicate which can evaluate it (like `is/2` or an arithmetic comparison).
3. You don't need the first clause, `insert2(nil, nil, nil)`. Or at least if you plan to account for inserting `nil`, I would suppose that the result should be the original tree, so it would be, `insert2(nil, Tree, Tree)` instead. You wouldn't nullify the tree just because you were attempting to insert `nil`. You would leave the tree alone.

Taking those factors into account:

```
% (3) Inserting nil into a Tree yields the same Tree
insert(nil, Tree, Tree).

% If you insert into an empty tree, the result is a tree with
%   a single node consisting of your new info
insert(Info, nil, t((Info, 1), nil, nil)).

% (1) If you insert into a tree and the node at the top matches your
%   Info, then you only increment the count of the top node
insert(Info, t((Info, C), L, R), t((Info, Cx), L, R)) :-
    Cx is C + 1.  % (2) `is/2` will evaluate; you can't do this "in-line"

% If you insert Info which is smaller than the top node value of
%   a non-nil tree, then you insert the Info into the left branch
insert(Info, t((I, C), L, R), t((I, C), Lx, R)) :-
    Info < I,
    insert(Info, L, Lx).

% If you insert Info which is greater than the top node value of
%   a non-nil tree, then you insert the Info into the right branch
insert(Info, t((I, C), L, R), t((I, C), L, Rx)) :-
    Info > I,
    insert(Info, R, Rx).
```

Comment: To be more robust, if you really do allow `nil` for `Info`, then the other predicates should check that `Info` is a number, *e.g.*, you could include `number(Info)` or `integer(Info)` as the first call in each of the other predicates.